# How to show number of users by dynamic age groups

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a table which store DoB of users. Now I need a report(crystal report) that shows how many users are there in ranges of age.

For example, the report need to shows:

Age: 1-10: 50 users

Age: 11-20: 30 users

Age: 21-30: 60 users
And so on...

The report should follow rules below :

1. The range of age can be changed easily (the range in example above is 10)
2. The last range is calculated automatically based on the oldest user

Actually I don't have any idea How to do it for now. I really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the ranges using arithmetic.  The exact syntax might vary by database, but it is basically:

```
select (floor( (a - 1) / 10 ) * 10 + 1) || '-' ||  (floor( (a - 1) / 10 ) * 10 + 10) as age_range,
       count(*)
from t
group by (floor( (a - 1) / 10 ) * 10 + 1) || '-' ||  (floor( (a - 1) / 10 ) * 10 + 10)
order by min(age);
```

The expression `floor( (a - 1) / 10 ) * 10 + 1` is just a mathematical expression that gets the first year of the range -- so 1-10 are in one group, 11-20, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your answer, to be honest I am not sure I get you exactly but does it means using your suggestion to create a function to calculate range which accept DoB as input and return range(ex 1-10, 11-20...). 

Then use this function to query range along with other fields, and group by range we can count users belong to range. 

Is that what you mean?

Comment: @ClearActionConsistent . . . Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: OMG it took me last few days just thinking about you suggestion, and now I got it. Thank again. I didn't implement it yet but I think I should mark your answer.